# Compare performance of linear regression models that differ by predictors used using cross validation

Tags: r, tidymodels

I would like to compare, using tidymodels and cross-validation, 3 linear regression models that can be specified as the following:

- (**model_A**) `y ~ a`
- (**model_B**) `y ~ b`
- (**model_AB**) `y ~ a + b`

In the following `y` will denote the target variable, while `a` and `b` will denote independent variables.

Without using cross validation it is (I hope) quite clear to me what I have to do:

1. Split my data into train and test set

```
set.seed(1234)
split <- data %>% initial_split(strata = y)
data_train <- training(split)
data_test <- training(split)
```

2. I can specify, fit, and evaluate my model in one go (for example for **model_AB**)

```
linear_reg() %>%
    set_engine("lm") %>%
    fit(y ~ a + b, data = data_train) %>%
    augment(new_data = data_test) %>%
    rmse(truth = y, estimate = .pred)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  .metric .estimator .estimate
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 rmse    standard       x.xxx
```

I can repeat step 2 for the other two models and compare the three models based on the RMSE metric (since this is the choice for this example).

For example I can create a dummy dataset and run the steps described above.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(1234)
n <- 1e4
data <- tibble(a = rnorm(n),
               b = rnorm(n),
               y = 1 + 3*a - 2*b + rnorm(n))

set.seed(1234)
split <- data %>% initial_split(strata = y)
data_train <- training(split)
data_test <- training(split)
```

- **Model_A**

```
linear_reg() %>%
    set_engine("lm") %>%
    fit(y ~ a, data = data_train) %>%
    augment(new_data = data_test) %>%
    rmse(truth = y, estimate = .pred)
```

result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  .metric .estimator .estimate
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 rmse    standard        2.23
```

- **Model_B**

```
linear_reg() %>%
    set_engine("lm") %>%
    fit(y ~ b, data = data_train) %>%
    augment(new_data = data_test) %>%
    rmse(truth = y, estimate = .pred)
```

result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  .metric .estimator .estimate
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 rmse    standard        3.17
```

- **Model_AB**

```
linear_reg() %>%
    set_engine("lm") %>%
    fit(y ~ a + b, data = data_train) %>%
    augment(new_data = data_test) %>%
    rmse(truth = y, estimate = .pred)
```

result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  .metric .estimator .estimate
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 rmse    standard        1.00
```

My question is: how can I evaluate the RMSE after performing cross validation on three models that differ by the list of possible features?

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3TkvZM60iU) Julia Silge does the job with three different models (logistic regression, knn, and decision trees) using the same set of predictors. However what I aim to do is to compare models that differ in the set of predictors.

Any suggestion and/or reference?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Thanks for your suggestion, dataset included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a lot of different models you want to compare, one way to deal with that is to use the [workflowsets](https://workflowsets.tidymodels.org/) package.

This way you can specify any number of models and preprocessors and it will run all of them and give you back the results in a tidy format.

Notice how we are using `recipe()` just denotes what variables are used in each model.

Additionally you can pass a `metric_set()` to the `metrics` in `workflow_map()` if you want to use different metrics than the defaults.

```r
library(tidymodels)
set.seed(1234)
n <- 1e4
data <- tibble(a = rnorm(n),
               b = rnorm(n),
               y = 1 + 3*a - 2*b + rnorm(n))

set.seed(1234)
split <- data %>% initial_split(strata = y)
data_train <- training(split)
data_test <- training(split)

lm_spec <- linear_reg()

rec_a <- recipe(y ~ a, data = data_train)
rec_b <- recipe(y ~ b, data = data_train)
rec_ab <- recipe(y ~ a + b, data = data_train)

all_models_wfs <- workflow_set(
  preproc = list(a = rec_a, b = rec_b, c = rec_ab),
  models = list(lm = lm_spec),
  cross = TRUE
)

all_models_wfs
#> # A workflow set/tibble: 3 × 4
#>   wflow_id info             option    result    
#>   <chr>    <list>           <list>    <list>    
#> 1 a_lm     <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[0]> <list [0]>
#> 2 b_lm     <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[0]> <list [0]>
#> 3 c_lm     <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[0]> <list [0]>

all_models_fit <- workflow_map(
  all_models_wfs, 
  resamples = vfold_cv(data_test),
  metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq, mape)
)

all_models_fit %>%
  collect_metrics()
#> # A tibble: 9 × 9
#>   wflow_id .config           preproc model .metric .esti…¹    mean     n std_err
#>   <chr>    <chr>             <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 a_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… mape    standa… 261.       10 3.99e+1
#> 2 a_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… rmse    standa…   2.26     10 2.89e-2
#> 3 a_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… rsq     standa…   0.627    10 7.72e-3
#> 4 b_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… mape    standa… 258.       10 2.07e+1
#> 5 b_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… rmse    standa…   3.10     10 2.13e-2
#> 6 b_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… rsq     standa…   0.298    10 7.61e-3
#> 7 c_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… mape    standa… 144.       10 3.66e+1
#> 8 c_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… rmse    standa…   1.01     10 6.51e-3
#> 9 c_lm     Preprocessor1_Mo… recipe  line… rsq     standa…   0.926    10 2.06e-3
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​.estimator
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! One question about your code: shouldn't you have specified the engine with the `set_engine` function?

Comment: That would have been better style-wise. Since we were using the `lm` engine I used that `linear_reg()` defaults to using the `lm` engine, and didn't specify it directly

Comment: All works perfectly. I have just a final side question to your approach that I will ask here. How can I change metric used?

Comment: I have updated the example to show how to change metrics